# Contradiction caused by 2-isogeny of elliptic curves?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E:y^2=x^3+x$ be an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Let  $E':y^2=x^3-4x$ be an another elliptic curve.

There is an isogeny  $\phi : E\to E'$ given by $(x,y)\to (\frac{y^2}{x^2},\frac{y(1-x^2)}{x^2})$.

This is called $2$-isogeny, because its degree is exactly $2$. Thus $Ker\phi\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.

Also, $\phi$ is surjective because it is nonzero morphism between curves.

But form first isomorphism theorem, $E(\Bbb{Q})/ker\phi \cong E'(\Bbb{Q})$・・・①.

But according to LMFDB, $E(\Bbb{Q})\cong E'(\Bbb{Q})\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.

Thus from ①, $0 \cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. This is unreasonable.

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: For any natural number $m$ multiplication $[m]:E\to E$ is an isogeny. You run into the exact same problem with suitable choices of $m$. But considering such isogenies may make it clearer that you need to go to an algebraic closure. For otherwise the kernel (= the full $m$-torsion, i.e. a subgroup of order $m^2$) won't be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existence of an isogeny $\phi:E\to E'$ only implies the existence of a (surjective) homomorphism between the groups of points over an algebraic closure:
$$E(\overline{\Bbb{Q}})/\mathrm{Ker}(\phi)\simeq E'(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}).$$
It also maps rational points to rational points, but that mapping need not be surjective.

Comment: The general fact at play is that a morphism between two projective curves over an algebraically closed field is either surjective or a constant.